# @types/styled-components Duplicate identifier FormData

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

If I add @types/styled-components in my project, I will have a bunch of errors in the build output:

```
ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts(36,15):
TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'FormData'.
  ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts(81,5):
TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'body' must be of type 'BodyInit', but here has type 'string | ArrayBuffer | DataView | Int8Array | Uint8Array | Uint8ClampedArray | Int16Array | Uint16Array | Int32Array | Uint32Array | Float32Array | Float64Array | Blob | FormData'.
  ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts(107,14):
TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'RequestInfo'.
  ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts(126,13):
TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'Response' must be of type '{ new (body?: BodyInit, init?: ResponseInit): Response; prototype: Response; error(): Response; redirect(url: string, status?: number): Response; }', but here has type '{ new (body?: string | ArrayBuffer | DataView | Int8Array | Uint8Array | Uint8ClampedArray | Int16Array | Uint16Array | Int32Array | Uint32Array | Float32Array | Float64Array | Blob | FormData, init?: ResponseInit): Response; prototype: Response; error: () => Response; redirect: (url: string, status?: number) => Res...'.
  ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts(196,5):
TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'abort' must be of type 'ProgressEvent', but here has type 'Event'.
  ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts(197,5):
TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'error' must be of type 'ProgressEvent', but here has type 'Event'.
  ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts(198,5):
TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'load' must be of type 'ProgressEvent', but here has type 'Event'.
  ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts(199,5):
TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'loadend' must be of type 'ProgressEvent', but here has type 'Event'.
  ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts(200,5):
TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'loadstart' must be of type 'ProgressEvent', but here has type 'Event'.
  ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts(201,5):
TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'progress' must be of type 'ProgressEvent', but here has type 'Event'.
  ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts(202,5):
TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'timeout' must be of type 'ProgressEvent', but here has type 'Event'.
  ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts(206,5):
TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'onabort' must be of type '(this: XMLHttpRequest, ev: ProgressEvent) => any', but here has type '(this: XMLHttpRequest, ev: Event) => any'.
  ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts(207,5):
TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'onerror' must be of type '(this: XMLHttpRequest, ev: ProgressEvent) => any', but here has type '(this: XMLHttpRequest, ev: Event) => any'.
  ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts(208,5):
TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'onload' must be of type '(this: XMLHttpRequest, ev: ProgressEvent) => any', but here has type '(this: XMLHttpRequest, ev: Event) => any'.
  ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts(209,5):
TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'onloadend' must be of type '(this: XMLHttpRequest, ev: ProgressEvent) => any', but here has type '(this: XMLHttpRequest, ev: Event) => any'.
  ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts(210,5):
TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'onloadstart' must be of type '(this: XMLHttpRequest, ev: ProgressEvent) => any', but here has type '(this: XMLHttpRequest, ev: Event) => any'.
  ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts(211,5):
TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'onprogress' must be of type '(this: XMLHttpRequest, ev: ProgressEvent) => any', but here has type '(this: XMLHttpRequest, ev: Event) => any'.
  ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts(212,5):
TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'ontimeout' must be of type '(this: XMLHttpRequest, ev: ProgressEvent) => any', but here has type '(this: XMLHttpRequest, ev: Event) => any'.
  ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts(243,6):
TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'XMLHttpRequestResponseType'.
  ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/@types/react-native/index.d.ts(9297,14):
TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'require'.
  ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/@types/react-native/index.d.ts(9315,11):
TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'console'.
  ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/@types/react-native/index.d.ts(9323,18):
TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'geolocation' must be of type 'Geolocation', but here has type 'GeolocationStatic'.
  ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/@types/react-native/index.d.ts(9326,11):
TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'navigator'.
  ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/@types/webpack-env/index.d.ts(203,13):
TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'require'.
  ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(5196,11):
TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'FormData'.
  ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(5206,13):
TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'FormData'.
  ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(16513,11):
TS2320: Interface 'Window' cannot simultaneously extend types 'GlobalFetch' and 'WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope'.
  Named property 'fetch' of types 'GlobalFetch' and 'WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope' are not identical.
  ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(17406,13):
TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'navigator'.
  ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(17510,13):
TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'console'.
  ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(17819,6):
TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'RequestInfo'.
  ERROR in /Users/me/projects/react/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(17992,6):
TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'XMLHttpRequestResponseType'.
```

For some reason it adds @types/react-native, which has some collisions with my react app.

I have the next tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react",
    "outDir": "./production/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

The problem could be solved with adding exact types in the type property into tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "types": [
      "jest",
      "jest-diff",
      "react",
      "react-dom",
      "react-intl",
      "react-redux",
      "react-router-dom",
      "webpack-env",
      "styled-components"
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

But this solution doesn't look nice to me. Is there any other fix?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Update 21/12/2020**

Move the styled-components/native types out of @types/styled-components and into its own package (@types/styled-components-react-native). If someone wants to use styled-components/native, all they need to do is install @types/styled-components-react-native and it will automatically augment the styled-components types (since TypeScript automatically includes any installed @types packages).

This makes it so that the main export (i.e., import styled from 'styled-components') works out-of-the-box (which is the most common usage). And in order to get styled-components/native all you need to do is install the other @types package, which is still easier than having to set types: [] in tsconfig.json.

(Solution copied from the Pull request)

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/49914

**Old**

I had the same issue and I solved downgrading @types/styled-components to 4.1.8.

You can achieve this by: `npm i @types/styled-components@4.1.8 --save-dev --save-exact`

This issue is still open for more than 1 year, all you will find are some workarounds.

About the problem, it seems that @types/styled-components require @types/react-native and this is causing problems with DOM lib. That means if you using react for the web you're going to have conflicts because of the react-native typings with the DOM lib. If you are using React-Native, you don't need to downgrade.**Try those below if you don't want to downgrade**:

For **NPM** users a possible workaround [mentioned in Github](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/33311#issuecomment-560230205) is adding:

```
"postinstall": "rm -rf node_modules/@types/react-native"
```

in your **package.json** to delete the types after you install them.

For **yarn** users you can create a **.yarnclean** file and add this content:

```
@types/react-native
```

as mentioned [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/33311#issuecomment-494477593).

You can find more information in this [issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/33311) on Github.

Comment: We also had to add `styled-components-react-native` to `paths` in tsconfig to get this to work, otherwise these types were not found.  (Apparently this is an issue if you already are setting `paths` in tsconfig.)  See https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/49914

Answer (score 16):

Adding `"skipLibCheck": true` to `compilerOptions` in the `tsconfig.json` file solved the issue for me. The solution comes from another project created by a newer `create-react-app`.

> Note: `"skipLibCheck": true` skips type checking of all declaration files ( *.d.ts ).

Comment: Not really... because of the implications that come with skipping lib checks.

Answer (score 5):

I ran across this, too. Simply downgrade from the latest version of @types/styled-components. 4.0.3 (no ^) and it seems to do the trick.

(found a bunch of other people referencing similar errors in the past with @types/node which presented a similar solution).

Answer (score 1):

Solution described by Arthur Brito is valid, but if you want to:

1. use latest version
2. and use `yarn` of  `@types/styled-components`

consider

1. removing from `node_modules`
2. and add `@types/styled-components` to `.yarnclean`

as suggested [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/33311#issuecomment-546727329)

Comment: This isn't really a solution, it just treats the symptoms

Answer (score 0):

npm + Yarn users:

1. Delete `node_modules/@types/react-native`
2. Delete dependency `"@types/react-native": "*"` in `node_modules/@types/styled-components/package.json`
3. Delete `dist` (`outDir` folder from `tsconfig.json`)

---

(1) will drop the duplicate global types. (2) will prevent `@types/react-native` from being reinstalled. (3) was additionally necessary for me. Other solutions didn't meet all my requirements:

```html
- use latest styled-components packages (+ TS 3.7 compatible)
- can be used with npm
- does not commit hack to VCS
- manually setting "types" in tsconfig.json isn't scalable
- --skipLibCheck creates weak types (it omits all `.d.ts` files type checks)
```

Issues:

- [DefinitelyTyped #1](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/33311)
- [DefinitelyTyped #2](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/33015)
- [Allow using dev dependencies in a package json](https://github.com/microsoft/types-publisher/pull/655)